# Отправка сообщений пользователя на email в Telebot python

Tags: python, telebot

Не хватает знаний довести до ума. Надо чтобы отправлялось сообщение пользователя на почту. SMTP работает через слово письмо.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def handle_start(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton(text='Оставить отзыв')
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton('Карта расположения автоматов')
    button3 = types.KeyboardButton('Отправить местоположение', request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button1, button2, button3)
    file = open('./Cat.jpeg', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет , расскажи нам о своем впечатлении ', reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
async def handle_message(message):
    keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='feedback')
    button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='feedback')
    keyboard1.add(button4, button5)
    if message.text == 'Оставить отзыв':
        await bot.reply_to(message, 'Вам понравился напиток?', reply_markup=keyboard1)
    if message.text == 'Карта расположения автоматов':
        await bot.reply_to(message, 'В разработке ;)')
    elif message.text == 'привет':
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'feedback':
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Готов принять ваш отзыв: ")
        await bot.register_next_step_handler(message, feedback_second)
async def feedback_second(message):
    await bot.forward_message(send_mail_text, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, отзыв был отправлен ")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'письмо')
async def send_mail_text(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Письмо отправлено')
    cormail = smtp.send_mail('Новое сообщение','coffee_life89@mail.ru', f'<p>User ID {message.from_user.id} От {message.from_user.first_name}</p>')
    asyncio.gather(asyncio.create_task(cormail))
asyncio.run(bot.polling())
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: А проблема то какая, в чем вопрос то?

Comment: я не знаю как реализовать отправку сообщения пользователя на почту через кнопку

Comment: А сама отправка сообщений то работает?

Comment: да, работает. письмо на почту приходит